# Problems when switching layouts using keyboard shortcuts specified in gsettings

Tags: fedora, gnome

I use gnome 40. In the gsettings, I set capslock as the switch for keyboard layout.
Problems when switching layouts using keyboard shortcuts specified in gsettings:

1. The layout change icon in the upper right corner does not change
2. you need to press 2 times on the layout switching buttons to change the language from the last in the list to the 1st one.

These problems were also present in previous versions of the gnome, tested on different computers and distributions.
Please tell me how to solve these problems. Thanks)

Comment: Try to use a ***combination of  three keys*** to switch between keyboard layouts. Just using a two key keyboard shortcut has been problematic for me for years now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the 'grp: alt_shift_toggle' key in gsettings to switch the layout (/ org / gnome / desktop / input-sources / xkb-options), then everything starts working as it should. If you remove the 'grp: caps_toggle' key and leave 'grp: alt_shift_toggle', then switching the layout also starts working as it should.